# Cannot Access Fields after adding Array to another Array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have an array of sections where a section is pushed into the array when the user clicks a checkbox.  It is defined like this:

```
$scope.print = {
  sections:[] 
};
```

Once I have all of the selected Sections, I use a service to get a list of questions for each selected section like this:

```
var questions = [];
myService.getQuestions(id)
  .success(function (data) {
    questions = data;
  });
```

Then I assign the returned questions to the original array like this:

```
angular.forEach($scope.print.sections,
    function (value, key) {
        if (value.QuestionSectionID === id) {
            $scope.print.sections[key].questions = questions;
        }
    });
```

The assignment "seems" to work, but I am unable to access the particular fields in the questions array by their field names.

On my HTML page, I have this:

```
<div ng-repeat="ps in print.sections">
    <div>
        <h4>{{ps.vchSectionName}}</h4>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="section in ps.questions">
        <div ng-repeat="q in section">
            {{q.vchQuestionText}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I try to access the "q.vchQuestionText" field, my HTML is blank, however if I simple do the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="q in section">
  {{q}}
</div>
```

I can then see ALL of the information contained in each field of "q".  But I need to access each field in "q" by it's name.  What am I missing here?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you give some sample data?

Comment: What exactly do you wish to see?  $scope.print.sections  is an array of sections.  Each Section has an id, and a name.  The questions array contains about 30 fields.

Comment: In js you have sections array with nested Questions array, but in html you use ngrepeat for Questions first and name each section

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  The first ng-repeat is "ps in print.sections", the second one "section in ps.questions"  gets the questions.

Comment: A section obviously contains more than an id and a name. It contains `QuestionSectionID` and `vchSectionName`. Maybe that's what you mean by "id and a name", but asking volunteers to guess at your data model will lead to confusion. Also, naming is important; you have `section in ps.questions`... why is that not `question in ps.questions`, since `ps` appears to be a section itself?

Comment: Actually, I was "told" to name it section because someone else told me that question in questions was confusing to them.  QuestionSectionId and vchSectionName is what was meant by id and a name.  I didn't name those, whoever built the database named those.

Comment: "Each Section has an id, and a name", which means that Section is an object, right? So what exactly is expected from `ng-repeat="q in section"`? Are you trying to loop through Section object's properties? Since section has only id and name, which of them has `vchQuestionText`?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the reason I could display all the data in "q", but could not specify a field is because I had one too many `ng-repeat` directives.

All I needed was the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="ps in print.sections">
<div>
    <h4>{{ps.vchSectionName}}</h4>
</div>
    <div ng-repeat="q in ps.questions">
        {{q.vchQuestionText}}
    </div>
 </div>
```

Hopefully, this will help someone else.  Thank you all for your help.